# Incorrect touch location on 4k screen

Tags: libgdx

I've been having some problems with touch detection on my current project, the problem is the higher the touch is on either axis the further off the touch point the touch registers.

In the image below you can see the issue i am talking about. The dot starts by rendering to the left of the mouse but by the time the mouse reaches the right side of the screen the dot is to the right of the mouse. The issue is much more obvious on the y axis.

[image]

The code running to create the above test is just the LibGDX SimpleTouchTest from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mouse%2C-touch-%26-keyboard so it is the absolute bare minimum.

The weird thing is, this only appears to be an issue on my laptop, on my desktop the dot sits under the mouse at all times. Both computers are running windows 10 so the only difference I can see is my laptop has a 4k display.

Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

Thanks
Adrian

Comment: What's resolution of each displays?

Comment: 1920x1080 on the desktop (which words correctly)
3840x2160 on the laptop

Comment: So this issue doesn't appear when the app is run in fullscreen mode so only window mode presents this issue

Comment: You probably need to transform the touch coordinates, can you post your code?

Comment: The above test is the libgdx touch example from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mouse%2C-touch-%26-keyboard#touch-point with no modifications. All unprojecting to convert coords is being done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason this is now working. Nothing has changed in the code so I can only assume something was out of wack within windows or the graphics driver that has some how sorted itself out over the last few weeks. Thanks to those that took the time to read my question.